# PHP undefined index when adding to SQL

Tags: php, sql

When editing my code I fear I have removed toomuch code, Here is my php;

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';


$inputId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputId']);
$inputReqDateWeek = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputReqDateWeek']);
$inputReqDateDay = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputReqDateDay']);
$inputOrderDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputOrdDate']);
$inputPriority = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputPriority']);
$inputDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputDescription']);

if ($inputReqDateDay =="Monday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 1;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Tuesday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 2;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Wednesday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 3;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Thursday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 4;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Friday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 5;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Saturday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 6;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Sunday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 7;
}


if ($inputReqDateDay =="Monday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 1;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Tuesday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 2;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Wednesday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 3;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Thursday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 4;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Friday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 5;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Saturday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 6;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Sunday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 7;
}

if(((isset($inputId) || trim($inputId) == '') || (isset($inputReqDateWeek) || trim($inputReqDateWeek) == '')|| (isset($inputReqDateDay) || trim($inputReqDateDay)== '') || (isset($inputOrderDate) || trim($inputOrderDate) == '') || (isset($inputPriority) || trim($inputPriority) == '')) && (is_numeric ($inputId)))
{
    $sql="INSERT INTO information (inputId, inputReqDateDay, inputReqDateWeek, inputOrderDate, inputPriority, inputDescription)
VALUES ('$inputId', '$inputReqDateDay', '$inputReqDateWeek', '$inputOrderDate', '$inputPriority', '$inputDescription')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}
echo "1 record added";
mysqli_close($con);
header('Location: ./insert.php') ;
}else{
echo "You did not fill out the required fields.";
}
mysqli_close($con);
exit();
?>

<form action="./script/insert.php" method="post">
        <div class="menuLeft">
        <p>Job ID: </p><input type="text" name="inputId" id="inputId" maxlength="4"><br>
        <p>Required Week: </p><input type="text" class="field" name="inputReqDateWeek" placeholder="01" id="inputReqDate" maxlength="8"><br>
        <p>Required Day: </p><select name="inputReqDateDay">
        <option>Monday</option>
        <option>Tuesday</option>
        <option>Wednesday</option>
        <option>Thursday</option>
        <option>Friday</option>
        <option>Saturday</option>
        <option>Sunday</option>
        </select><br>
        <p>Order date: </p><input type="text" name="inputOrdDate" maxlength="8" id="inputOrderDate" value="<?php
        echo date("d/m/y");
        ?>"><br>
        <p>Order status </p><select name="inputPriority" class="field">
        <option>On order</option>
        <option>On hold</option>
        <option>High priority</option>
        <option>Complete</option>
        </select><br>
    </div>
    <div class="menuRight">
        <p>Job Description (Optional) :</p><textarea rows="6" name="inputDescription" id="inputJobDesk"></textarea>
        <input type="image" src="button.png" id="sendForm" alt="Submit Form" />
    </div>
    </form>
```

The form works fine, It will post to the database, However it throws errors at me saying that all the form variables ($inputId, $inputReqDateDay etc...) are an "undefined index". The fields are definitely full as they are posted onto the database. If any more code is required please ask.

Contents of $_POST

```
Array ( [inputId] => 2323 
        [inputReqDateWeek] => 08 
        [inputReqDateDay] => Monday 
        [inputOrdDate] => 11/06/14 
        [inputPriority] => On order 
        [inputDescription] => ddd 
        [x] => 56 
        [y] => 15 
      )
```

Comment: Always use "isset()" around your $_POST values and sanitize them (inputId should be an int? so don't let me send you a string, for example)

Comment: @JakeGould Yeah, a lot of them are these days. I'm glad I'm out of the rat race. It's "comments" all the way for this country lad ;-)

Comment: @JakeGould Lucky for me I was a (graphic) designer "before" getting into the back-end of Web stuff. I've some 20+ years under my belt in graphics and then some ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting `Notice: Undefined index` errors, it’s most likely because `$_POST` is empty or not being sent. To see what is in there check a dump of `$_POST` like this:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
```

Change these lines:

```
$inputId = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputId']);
$inputReqDateWeek = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputReqDateWeek']);
$inputReqDateDay = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputReqDateDay']);
$inputOrderDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputOrdDate']);
$inputPriority = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputPriority']);
$inputDescription = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['inputDescription']);
```

To this:

```
// Set the post array.
$post_array = array('inputId','inputReqDateWeek','inputReqDateDay','inputOrdDate','inputPriority','inputDescription');

// Roll through the post array & set related variables.
foreach ($post_array as $post_key => $post_value) {
  $$post_key = isset($_POST[$post_key]) && !empty($_POST[$post_key]) ? mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST[$post_key]) : null;
}
```

If the `$_POST` keys are basically the same as the variables you are setting & you are performing the same `mysqli_real_escape_string` on each, you might as well automate the process to make it easier to handle.

And specific to this question, the code now checks via `isset()` and `!empty()` so that should eliminate an `Notice: Undefined index` issues.

Also you have this chunk of code in there twice for no apparent reason:

```
if ($inputReqDateDay =="Monday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 1;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Tuesday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 2;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Wednesday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 3;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Thursday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 4;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Friday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 5;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Saturday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 6;
}elseif ($inputReqDateDay =="Sunday") {
    $inputReqDateDay = 7;
}
```

Why not just change that to an array like this:

```
// Set the final '$inputReqDateDay_array'
$inputReqDateDay_array = array();
$inputReqDateDay_array['Monday'] = 1;
$inputReqDateDay_array['Tuesday'] = 2;
$inputReqDateDay_array['Wednesday'] = 3;
$inputReqDateDay_array['Thursday'] = 4;
$inputReqDateDay_array['Friday'] = 5;
$inputReqDateDay_array['Saturday'] = 6;
$inputReqDateDay_array['Sunday'] = 7;

// Set the final '$inputReqDateDay'
$inputReqDateDay = $inputReqDateDay_array[$inputReqDateDay];
```

Comment: Thanks, Shouldn't `$post_array(` be `$post_array = (` ? It is saying undefined variable $post_array

Comment: So using the code you just sent me I now get lots of undefined variables when trying to insert `inputId` into the database, Do I need to change the way I insert?

Comment: Outputs : `Array
(
    [inputId] => 2323
    [inputReqDateWeek] => 08
    [inputReqDateDay] => Monday
    [inputOrdDate] => 11/06/14
    [inputPriority] => On order
    [inputDescription] => ddd
    [x] => 56
    [y] => 15
)`
I have no idea what the x and y variable is

Answer (score 1):

before submitting pass the [isset(](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.isset.php)) function on all the $_POST variables.